# Android: Removing "The" from listview items

Tags: android, listview

I have received several requests to adjust the way list items are displayed on my media player application.

Currently any entry beginning with "The" is sorted with the T's as you would expect.  Many users would like to sort the item using the second word in the title.

Can someone shed some light on where this would be done?  Would it be adjusted while getting the cursor or when applying to listview?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You,
Josh

UPDATE:

Thank you all for the answers, but I am still struggling to find apply the solutions suggested in my instance.

I am using a simple cursor to acquire the dataset.  Snippet of the code it below:

```
audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cols, 
            null, null,AudioColumns.ARTIST + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        startManagingCursor(audioCursor);        


        setListAdapter(new MyABCAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,
                audioCursor, new String[]{AudioColumns.ARTIST,MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS}, 
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}));
```

I also have a utility that successfully adjusts the entry text, changing "The Artist" to "Artist, The", but it is not applied until bindView and the list has already been sorted:

```
private String fixFileName(String fileName) {
    ...
    if (fileName.startsWith("The")){

        fileName = fileName.replace("The ", "");
        fileName = fileName.concat(",The");
    }


    return fileName;
}
```

My questions are:

1)  Is there any way to apply fixFileName to the Cursor before the list is created?
   2)  If that is not possible, is there a way to resort the listview after bindview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have your list items extend [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).  In the `compareTo(..)` method, write the custom compare code, likely using a `"the".equalsIgnoreCase(fileName.subString(0, 3))`, to make "The..." a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an `ArrayList<String>` for the titles? One way I can think of is to implement your own `Comparable` interface. That would include, inside the method `compareTo(...)`, remove any word like "The, "A", etc. and return the comparison of the rest of the String.

Answer (score 0):

When you add items into the list do a Collections.sort() with a custom Comparator.

```
class CustomComp implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)
    {
        ...
        if(obj1.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("the"))
             sort by second word instead
        ...
    }
}
```